# Unit of distance in Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am calculating the distance between 2 points using Google Maps API, but the problem is:

what is the units that API returns in distance (especially the **value** and not text)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Google Maps JavaScript API Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Distance) says that the `value` property of the `google.maps.Distance` object is the "distance in meters".